# Ansible/Jinja "from_yaml" filter sorting keys in the original file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to read a YML file from a remote node in Ansible and make modifications and update it.

When I use "from_yaml" Jinja filter, I notice that the keys are sorted and when I update the file on remote, it will cause issues.

Is there a way to set Sort_Keys=False on the from_yaml filter?

**Original file:**

```
key1:
  key5:
    key3: value3
  key2:
    key5: value4
  key6:
    key7: value5
```

**After applying "from_yaml" filter (the keys are sorted):**

```
key1:
  key2:
    key3: value3
  key5:
    key5: value4
  key6:
    key7: value5
```

Answer (score 2):

YAML standard says that there is no order of keys in a dictionary. Python3 recently(I don't remember the version. Probably 3.6 or 3.7. You can find it in the release notes.) introduced ordered keys in dictionaries. This is what you see as a result of the filter *from_yaml*. You'll see the dictionary also ordered without any filter when Ansible uses recent Python3. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    key1:
      key5:
        key3: value3
      key2:
        key5: value4
      key6:
        key7: value5
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: key1
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  key1:
    key2:
      key5: value4
    key5:
      key3: value3
    key6:
      key7: value5
```

But, Jinja, even when using Python3.8, doesn't sort the dictionaries (I don't know why). For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for k,v in key1.items() %}
          {{ k }}: {{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    key5: {'key3': 'value3'}
    key2: {'key5': 'value4'}
    key6: {'key7': 'value5'}
```

To answer your question, unfortunately, there is no such option as `Sort_Keys=False`. Moreover, in YAML, there is no guarantee in what order the keys of a dictionary are stored. If you want to be sure that you write a dictionary in a specific order you have to keep the list of the keys. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for k in list_of_keys %}
          {{ k }}: {{ key1[k] }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        list_of_keys: [key5, key2, key6]
```

Answer (score 1):

The imported data is organized in the data structure of a dict. In contrast to an array (or list), in which elements are ordered in their position and addressed via an index, the values of a dict are addressed via the respective key. However, you have no possibility to define or influence the order. Ansible always outputs a data structure of a Dict sorted by the keys.

The example you gave is wrong. Because the data structure is not changed even if the output is sorted by keys. `key1.key5.key3` still returns the value `value3`. But in your example "After applying "from_yaml" filter" this value does not exist anymore, in your case `value3` is now under `key1.key2.key3`. Your output does not match the output Ansible gives when the `from_yaml` filter is applied to said input.

---

Data file `mydata.txt`:

```yaml
key1:
  key5:
    key3: value3
  key2:
    key5: value4
  key6:
    key7: value5
```

Ansible Task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('file', 'mydata.txt') | from_yaml }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "key1": {
            "key2": {
                "key5": "value4"
            },
            "key5": {
                "key3": "value3"
            },
            "key6": {
                "key7": "value5"
            }
        }
    }
}
```